# css3 animation not working on mobile chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a background animation transition. it works on chrome, but not on chrome mobile. may i know which part is wrong? thanks.

```
.slideshow,
.slideshow:after { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}


.slideshow li{
    list-style: none;
}

.slideshow li span { 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s; 
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s; 
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 32s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../img/sbg.jpg); 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../img/sbg2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 8s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: 8s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../img/sbg3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 16s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../img/sbg4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried inclduing webkit?

```
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```